# Unable to update fields using anonymous block in Oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-18.2

I have 2 pages in my Apex application and page1 and Page 2.

In Page1- I have 2 fields which I am just saving so that I can use it in Page2 to insert completely in the table with Primary key being a sequence that I created.

In Page 2: primary key is hidden(sequence),

I have a Save Button on which I have written a anonymous block(dynamic Action--> Execute PLSQL code) to insert into the table with both Page1 and page 2 Details, which went successfully and no problem with it.

But the problem is with Update button.

I am again using anonymous block(dynamic Action--> Execute PLSQL code) to update the details on the page2. But the records are not getting updated in the database.

I am using Join condition of

Id=:P6_PRIMARY_KEY (:P6_PRIMARY_KEY is the hidden field  and Id is the database field with a sequence)

I think I am not able to fetch the Id in the where condition.

Not sure If I am missing something.

I have done the inserting into the database using the similar anonymous block and it went well and creates a records whenever I click on Save button.

And I am doing the same for Update button. It doesnt update with no error as well.

My Primary Key is a sequence. I Think somehow it is not keeping the value of the primary key. I need to change something in my where condition maybe.

Comment: From my experience, saving or updating data from "just-inserted" Items in a page tends to be troublesome due to the values not being in the session, unless you're using a Submit Page function on the button. You could try checking the values in your session values tab (the one at the bottom of the page for developers) and see if your data truly is what you're inputting, after you do.

Answer (score 1):

Unhide `P6_PRIMARY_KEY` so that you'd see what's in there. Perhaps you're fetching a new sequence number each time so - no wonder that join doesn't work. If that's the case, adjust the process that does that, either by applying `IF`, e.g.

```
if :P6_PRIMARY_KEY is null then
   :P6_PRIMARY_KEY := seq_name.nextval;
end if;
```

or by setting the condition for the process, e.g. *Item is null* (which one? `P6_PRIMARY_KEY`, of course).

Also, enable debugging, run the page, perform update and then view debug results. It'll show values of all items, code that was executed so it'll probably help to find the culprit.

Comment: It worked for me now, In my Update Button(the PLSQL code for updating the values) I just used this for Hidden value after the update statement Returning id INTO :P^_PRIMARY_KEY and it actually fetches the values fro DB into session and i can insert the specific record now.

Comment: Nice; I'm glad you fixed it. Thank you for letting us know.